# Stop my timer when the screen touch happen

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I want stop the timer if the action of touching screen is executed, because now when I touch screen the timer still running and there's no function that made him stop.
can you help me

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
RelativeLayout splash;
    Handler handler;
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashfile);

                    handler=new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    },10000);

       /*splash=findViewById(R.id.splash);
              splash.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
                return true;
            }
        });*/
            }
            
}
```

Comment: Stop the Handler with this handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);  in dispatchTouchEvent before the intent try this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all the callbacks on `Handler` using `removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`

```
splash=findViewById(R.id.splash);
splash.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // this will remove your callback
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
        return true;
    }
});
```